# How to add cropper on a particular View(other than ImageView)

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview

I need to implement a cropper in my project. Problem is I found croppers that works with UIImageView. But I have a pdf. I am viewing it using code found on vfr/Reader.GitHub. I need to add a cropper, that will crop the particular page of the PDF. In code am using a ScrollView to show the PDF. Any code? any reference that crops the topmost view? Or the Window?

Answer (score 0):

use view.layer.mask property to mask the portion that you want to see.

```
 CAShapeLayer *layer =[CAShapeLayer layer];
 layer.path =[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect...].CGPath;
 view.layer.mask =layer;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single pdf page, the vfr library already has page thumbnails functionality which are basically single page images.. you can find ways of directly using those thumbnails.

If however you want to 'crop' a portion of the page, you will have to render the PDF page in a core graphics context, allow user to select the area (or select the predefined area as per your requirements) and crop the context.

You can then render this contet wherever you like or convert this context to jpeg data and save it to a file.

Read the [iOS Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-SW9) to get a better idea of drawing views, PDFs images etc into core graphics contexts and working with core graphics contexts in more detail: